# Ошибка DuplicateServiceException при деплое spring приложения на wildfly

Tags: spring, развертывание, jboss, wildfly

Пытаюсь задеплоить CRUD-приложение на Wildfly 10. В проекте два дата сорца для соединения с продакшен и дев базами данных. Каждая конфигурация для дата сорца помечена спринговой аннотацией `@Profile`. Для указания профиля в standalone.xml добавил в JVM_OPTS `-Dspring.profiles.active=production`. При запуске wildfly вижу в jvm_opts данную строку. После деплоя своего приложения, нажимаю enable и получаю следующую ошибку:

```
org.jboss.msc.service.DuplicateServiceException: 
Service jboss.pojo.\"org.jboss.netty.internal.LoggerConfigurator\".
DESCRIBED is already registered"}}
```

Как можно поправить проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решилась полным перезапуском сервера.

Действительно, в проекте два бина с одним интерфейсом, поэтому автоматическое связывание затрудняется с тем какой бин использовать. Бины помечены соответствующими аннотациями @Profile и в java opts на wildfly указан профиль. Однако, при каждом новом деплое приложения приходится полностью перезапускать сервер, чтобы устранить ошибку.